# Gridview RadioButtonList Validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have one grid-view inside grid-view using one `RadioButtonList` and outside grid-view using one asp.net `Button` when user click that button all radio button list should be selected, then only that `Button` event should be submitted.

Below is my grid-view `RadioButtonList`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add Score">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" CssClass="cssrbt">
<asp:ListItem Text="Correct" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Wrong" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Below is my button which using out side of gridview.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-md btn-danger" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click"  ValidationGroup="viva" />
```

My issue is without selection inserting all grid-view data and that I want to validate.

Comment: Please this question is unclear. You has tagged it a `javascript` / `jquery`and by now, there is no javascript issues.

Comment: Hello I am using below answer java script, can you help for this solution, please check below answer. @mcNets

Answer (score 0):

You can bind javascript client event to button and iterate each radiobuttonlist to validate if atleast on radio button is selected.

```
$('<%= btn_Submit.ClientID %>').click(function(){
  $('.cssrbt').each(function(){
    if($(this).find(':radio:selected').length == 0)
         console.log("One of radio button list option must be selected")
  });
});
```

Comment: Wait I am cheeking. @Adil

Comment: I am not getting any message and directly taking submission without validation same issue and I am using content page of master page. @Adil

Comment: I am getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…). @Adil

Comment: Include latest jQuery in your page

Comment: I added this script then also nothing alert is coming: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> . @Adil

Comment: console.log("One of radio button list option must be selected") will right in console use alert("invalid"); also debug javascript code to know what is happening, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: Now I am getting this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and press f12 and checked. @Adil

Comment: What resource? debug and find out! also check if you can download the jQuery file from the link you added.

Comment: Can you provide one script and I resolve resource error, nothing is coming, java script button click only not firing. @Adil

Comment: where did you put this javascript code? add in document.ready event also make sure document.ready is fired, https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            
       

        $('<%= btn_Submit.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $('.cssrbt').each(function () {
                alert('hi');
                if ($(this).find(':radio:selected').length == 0)
                    console.log("One of radio button list option must be selected")
            });
        }); 

        });</script> . @Adil

Comment: see above is my code one more think I want to tell gridview and button should be inside in update panel?. @Adil

Answer (score 0):

The example that adil gave needs JQuery library to implement and if you dont want to use any library only javascript you can validate like this

```
 <form runat="server" id="form1" action="Test.aspx.cs">

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add Score">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" CssClass="cssrbt">
<asp:ListItem Text="Correct" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Wrong" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>


</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


          <asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-md btn-danger" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return Validate('RadioButtonList1')" OnClick="btn_Submit_OnClick"  />

    </form>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                function Validate(id) {
                    var radiobutton = document.getElementsByName(id);
                    var flag;
                    for (var j = 0; j < radiobutton.length; j++) {
                        if (radiobutton[j].checked !== true) {
                            flag = true;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }


                    }

                    if (flag) {
                        alert("Please select one option");
                        return false;

                    } 
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: I told you in above question button is outside of gridview not inside of gridview. @Usman

Comment: i did update the answer and button is now outside grid view as you can see in code

Comment: I already tried but not working event alert also not coming. @Usman

Comment: Not error is showing and one more think I want to tell gridview and button should be inside in update panel? becuase page is loading. @Usman